# How to monitor heat of x86 Intel Processor generated by running an application?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

I am running a code of an application on my x86 Intel processor. I want to monitor the temperature (Thermal Profile) deviation caused by the application. How can I see in Linux? Are there such commands that I can run on terminal?
Thanks

Comment: There are tons of temperature monitor software out there. Also, most sensors provide a mapping in sysfs under `/sys/class/hwmon`. For example, I can do `cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, It shows temperature after running my application. I checked it before and after and It shows 4000 and 39000. What is this? And how can I check while I am running an application.

Comment: Nobody stops you from checking it while your app is running in another terminal. The value may be encoded, or not absolute. See also the `sensors` command.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature

Comment: Thanks @Johan. There is a lot of help to monitor.